# get to root folder of website project from codebehind (.net)

Tags: .net, directory, root, code-behind

I have a .net-website project and want to get some file from app_data folder.

I know I can get the folder in markup like this:

```
"~/App_Data/myfile.csv"
```

But from Code-behind, I tried

```
File.OpenWrite(String.Format(@"~/App_Data/myfile.csv"));
```

resulting in error

"Could not find path \"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\~\App_Data\myfile.csv\" (translated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `String.Format` method doesn't do any URL conversion. Use the `MapPath` method to get the physical path of a virtual address:

```
File.OpenWrite(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/myfile.csv"))
```